# Enabling regex support on AWS Managed ElasticSearch in painless scripts

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I am trying to upload templates to my AWS managed ElasticSearch.

ElasticSearch responds with a 500 error complaining that I need to set `script.painless.regex.enabled` to `true`. I know that you cannot edit the `elasticsearch.yml` file directly, but is there anyway to allow for support of regex in painless scripts on AWS managed ES?

Comment: did you get a solution?

Comment: @zakwan no I don't think they allow regex support on AWS. Ended up changing my application.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way yet to use regex under AWS ES cluster.

You can try to use StringTokenizer, as following example:

example value:

```
doc['your_str_field.keyword'].value = '{"xxx":"123213","yyy":"123213","zzz":"123213"}'
```

Painless script:

```
{
"script": {
"lang": "painless",
"inline": "String xxx = doc['your_str_field.keyword'].value; xxx = xxx.replace('{','').replace('}','').replace('\"','').replace(' ','');StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(xxx, ',');tokenizer.nextToken();tokenizer.nextToken();StringTokenizer tokenizer_v = new StringTokenizer(tokenizer.nextToken(),':');tokenizer_v.nextToken();return tokenizer_v.nextToken();"
}
}
```

also, I needed to increase max_compilations_rate

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
"transient": {
  "script.max_compilations_rate": "500/1m"
}
}
```