# Elastic search fill field B with array of words from the value of field A in document

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, cpu-word, elasticsearch-5

I would like to add a field B, which should contain an array with words of field A. I would like to use some kind of script which breaks down the value of Field A into sections of words.

So something like this:
Field A: "The Quick Brown Fox"
Field B: ["The","Quick","Brown","Fox"]

I'm struggling with googling how to achieve this in ElasticSearch 5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the [update by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/docs-update-by-query.html) and a script that splits fieldA and stores the resulting array into fieldB:

```
POST test/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.fieldB = /\\s+/.split(ctx._source.fieldA);",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

You'll get this:

```
    {
      "fieldA" : "The brown fox",
      "fieldB" : [
        "The",
        "brown",
        "fox"
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Trying this gives me the following error:

        "type": "parse_exception",
        "reason": "expected one of [inline], [file] or [stored] fields, but found none"

I've replaced fieldB with "zoektermen" and fieldA with "hoofdtitel".

Comment: Sorry, you're using 5.6 and I tested on 6.5... Check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I need to set Regex enabled to true. I use ElasticSearch on AWS. I googled, and apparently I'm not able to change the value in AWS.  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47271384/enabling-regex-support-on-aws-managed-elasticsearch-in-painless-scripts) 

Do you know a second solution?

Comment: Yes, split that field at indexing time :-) or better: migrate to ES Cloud which is by far much much better than AWS managed ES.

Comment: You can find a good comparison [here](https://www.elastic.co/aws-elasticsearch-service) and and older one [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/hosted-elasticsearch-services-roundup-elastic-cloud-and-amazon-elasticsearch-service)